# When I resubmit my app after a rejection do I need to increment the version number?

Tags: iphone, app-store, version, appstore-approval, submission

My app was rejected, so I have amended it and am about to resubmit it. The first time I submitted it it was as version 1.0. Do I need to increment the version number for this resubmission?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Comment: @Makyen this is a developer go-to community. A lot of help regarding everything related to programming has been received here. Closing questions like this mean you do not support developer growth. And that's a thumbs down for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No!!! You do not need to update version number.**  If your app is rejected then you do not need to change its version number.

Change the app status "Ready to submit" on iTunes connect and submit it.

Answer (score 4):

Upload the binary again with same version number but preferably you can change the build number.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create a new version number, especially if it doesn't add features and you're just fixing a small bug or rejection. But! In my XCode 7.3, I needed to increment the "build number" in the app "Identity" settings. This will fix the **Redundant binary upload** error you may receive. It's sort of like making a "patch" build from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After your app has been rejected, the only thing you have to do is to clear the bugs that leaded to rejection and submit the new binary.

No changes to app version is needed.

Answer (score 0):

No, you just need to upload the binary again and again the review process will be done.