# How do you replace a rejected app store binary if the version number should not be incremented?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My app store submission was rejected and I'm trying to upload a replacement.

This answer says the version number should not be incremented:

[When I resubmit my app after a rejection do I need to increment the version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984356/when-i-resubmit-my-app-after-a-rejection-do-i-need-to-increment-the-version-numb)

On the iTunesConnect build page I deleted the previous build that got rejected and saved the page, but then when trying to submit the new archive from Xcode I got the Redundant Binary Upload error.

So if I'm not supposed to increment the build number, but I've already deleted the original build, and I still can't submit the new version how do I proceed?

Comment: Change the build number of your new build to the old one?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do this. You must increment the build number for every upload. My guess is that this restriction enforces that testers using testflight can be confident in the build number corresponding to only a single build. If it makes you feel any better, the build number isn't visible to users AFAIK.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Keep the same *version* number, but change your *build* number.

For example, if the original Version is 1.0 and the original Build is 1.0, you can keep the Version as 1.0 but change the Build to 1.0.1 to avoid that error.

[image]